# Assigning Prefix-Flexible Static IPv6 Addresses to Servers

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ipv6

Sometimes it's desirable to assign a server a static IPv6 addresses. Hand-configuring a static global unicast IPv6 address is one way to do this but necessitates manual updating any time the address prefix needs changing.

Is there a proper/best way to assign a static IPv6 address to a Windows Server that preserves the ability to use Router Announcements to reconfigure the address's prefix or is what I'm trying to do not the IPv6 way of doing things?

One way to achieve this would be to assign the device/server a static link local address. However, in my research, I normally didn't hear this idea mentioned, making me wonder if it is not a recommended approach.

Comment: SLAAC will always give you the same predictable host-part of an address on any given interface. But if you replace the NIC, then the address will change... DHCPv6 reservations are also possible.